# SQL "Must declare the scalar variable"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I keep getting this error but I don't know why as I've already declared the variable.

```
DECLARE @SizeAttributeTable TABLE (
    Id int NOT NULL identity(0,1), 
    PpamId int, PvavId int, 
    AttributeName varchar(20), 
    AttributeValue varchar(50), 
    ProductId int
)


INSERT INTO @SizeAttributeTable (PpamId, PvavId, AttributeName, AttributeValue, ProductId )
   SELECT 
       ppam.Id, pvav.ProductVariantAttributeId, pa.Name, pvav.Name, p.Id 
   FROM 
       ProductVariantAttributevalue pvav, Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping ppam, Product p, ProductAttribute pa 
   WHERE 
       [pvav].ProductVariantAttributeId = [ppam].Id 
       AND [p].Id = ppam.ProductId 
       AND [pa].Id = [ppam].ProductAttributeId 
       AND pa.Name = 'Size'
   ORDER BY 
       p.Id, pvav.Id, pvav.Name 

print(@SizeAttributeTable) --error points here
```

Can anyone advise me? Thanks

Comment: *scalar* is the key point here. *scalar* variable's contain a *single* value.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 4):

You can't "print" a table, you can `SELECT * FROM @SizeAttributeTable` though.

`Print` is generally for displaying a single value of datatypes other than tables like:

```
DECLARE @SomeString VARCHAR(20) = 'Test Print'
PRINT(@SomeString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Print a table value variable is prohibited in sql server. try using SELECT statement